# Unable to access context object in HTML page rendered in Django

Tags: python, django

The below view function send `news` object to HTML page but HTML page gives no result/blank page.

```
def Newsdetail(request,slug):
    news = get_object_or_404(News,slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'newsfront/news_detail.html', {news:news})
```

below is the model

```
class News(models.Model):
    title=models.TextField()
    ..........

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Newsdetail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

HTML PAGE

```
 <h5>{{news.title}}</h5>
```

Comment: You're passing context incorectly it should be dictionary like this ``{'news':news}`` instead of ``{news:news}``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suppose the return statement of your Newsdetail view should look like this:

```
def Newsdetail(request, slug):
    news = get_object_or_404(News, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'newsfront/news_detail.html', {'news':news})
```